# How to make all variables in javascript script have two decimal points

Tags: javascript, variables, rounding

community :)

I'm building a webpage and I need to show prices from external javascript variables into HTML table. Variables are declared like this:

```
var price1 = 256.6;
var price2 = 220.36;
```

Then I write these variables into HTML with internal script using .innerHTML() function. What I want is to make all variables in external javascript have 2 decimal points. I can use:

```
var price11 = price1.toFixed(2);
var price22 = price2.toFixed(2);
```

But I have too many variables to apply the conversion to each of them individually. So is there a way to convert all the variables on the entire script to have two decimal points?

Comment: Create a function and use it

Comment: No. Where those values come from? You should perform your rounding on the source.

Comment: why not use with arrays? and then round it in a loop

Comment: they come from external javascript

Comment: You will have to be more specific.  Where are the data? What do the variables look like?  Do you have them in an array? ...

Comment: @Gustas That could mean a lot of things. *How* do they come from an "external javascript"? Are they the return value of a function? Are they defined in an array?

Comment: Is there a reason why they don't have two decimal places in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know there is no way of doing that in core Javascript. You may have to write a on load function or some times there may be libraries to do that. But you will have to find hard for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

1. either you round the number where is generated (at the source - from the library or endpoint)
2. or you round them locally

Answer (score 0):

If the external file has global variables, you can do this:

```js
//External file
var price1 = 1.2569;
var price2 = 5.5762;

//Script
var tmp, i = 1;

while(tmp = window["price" + i]){
   window["price" + i + "" + i++] = tmp.toFixed(2)
}

document.write(price11);
document.write("<br>");
document.write(price22)
```

Answer (score 0):

Show prices in integer amount of cent units of your currency: after applying e.g. 2% discounts, you can force the values to be handled as integers using bitwise operators:

```
+var|0;   // '+' handles also objects
```

Then you need to have a function to show the prices with the decimal point in the correct place.

This is by the way the only way to guarantee prices to add up.